# Assigning an element to a variable

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling with assigning an element to a variable - am I missing the plot here?

```
animationupgrades = [{
    animation: "height",
    target: $('#element'),
    effect: 33,
    finished: 23
}];

var thisIndex = 0; //as an example

var aniAttribute = animationupgrades[thisIndex].animation;
var target = animationupgrades[thisIndex].target;
var effect = animationupgrades[thisIndex].effect;
var finished = animationupgrades[thisIndex].finished;

$(target).on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        aniAttribute : effect
    },500);
    console.log("errr");
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        aniAttribute : finished
    },500);
});
```

edit: Sorry, it was actually an object - I typo'd! Why all the downvotes?

edit2: a fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/28wone62/

Comment: you missed the brackets

Comment: that was a typo - i've corrected it now - apologies

Comment: I didnt downvote you, and that's what I thought typo

Comment: have you tried of doing something different with target? like changing something target.css('background', 'red')?

Comment: the assignment works, is animation what is not working

Comment: I'm almost there, it works when replace aniAttribute with "height", do'n know yet why

Comment: I'm at an end - can't work it out :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object definition

```
var aniAttribute = "height";
{ aniAttribute : "literal" }
```

defines an attribute called "aniAttribute" not an attribute called "height"

here a posible solution.

```js
animationupgrades = [{
    animation: "height",
    target: $('#element'),
    effect: 33,
    finished: 23
}];

var thisIndex = 0; //as an example

var attr = animationupgrades[thisIndex].animation;
var target = animationupgrades[thisIndex].target;
var effect = animationupgrades[thisIndex].effect;
var finished = animationupgrades[thisIndex].finished;

$(target).on('mouseover', function() {
    console.log("a", attr, target, effect + "px", finished);
    var obj = {};
    obj[attr] = effect + "px";
    $(this).stop().animate(obj, 500);
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    var obj = {};
    obj[attr] = finished + "px";
    $(this).stop().animate(obj,500);
});
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;  
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red" id="element">
  asdasdasdasd
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry! That was a typo.

Comment: ahh.. just let me see it again

Comment: any joy? it's driving me insane

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   animationupgrades = [ {
        animation: "height",
        target: $('#element'),
        effect: 33,
        finished: 23 }
   ];
```

Comment: The missing brackets was a typo - I've corrected this now